# Converting JPEG Images to Black and White

Tags: c, image, jpeg

Is there any specific way to convert jpeg images to black and white using C? I converted a .bmp image to black and white using C by simply extracting the headers (which in .bmp file is 54 bytes in length) and converting the RGB to the respective gray level using the formula.
But how to do that in jpeg file?

Comment: You have to learn how to speak JPEG by studying the specification, or otherwise use a library like libjpeg.

Comment: Try to find some library

Comment: is that library available in C. And is there any way other than the library since the bmp files are pretty well solvable without any library.

Comment: @bluechill libjpeg is written in C, and it's very good at what it does.  Unlikely you can do a better job of it, since JPG is a very complex affair.

Comment: "Converting a jpeg to black and white (well, grayscale) is easy. Just throw away the U and V channels and keep only the Y channel. :-)

Comment: @bluechill [just google it](http://bit.ly/A1aCzg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can afford to link a library, I highly recommend OpenCV for this task: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/

Comment: As mentioned in the question comments, this can be done losslessly by processing the JPEG compressed data. Opening with OpenCV, processing, and recompressing may introduce some artifacts.